# AttributeError: type object 'Score' has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I am trying to make a scoreboard API in fastAPI using tortoise-orm for ORM.
I am facing some error, I have absolutely no idea why, as my Score class has the attribute date.

main.py:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

from scoreboard.models import (Score, ScoreIn_Pydantic, Team, Team_Pydantic,
                               TeamIn_Pydantic)

app = FastAPI()
db: list[Team] = []
register_tortoise(app=app,
                  db_url="sqlite://db.sqlite3",
                  modules={"models": ["scoreboard.models"]},
                  generate_schemas=True,
                  add_exception_handlers=True)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return True


@app.get("/score")
async def get_score() -> list[Team_Pydantic]:
    return await Team_Pydantic.from_queryset(Team.all())


@app.get("/score/{team_name}")
async def get_team_score(team_name: str):
    return Team_Pydantic.from_queryset_single(Team.get(name=team_name))


@app.put("/score")
async def post_score(team: TeamIn_Pydantic, score: ScoreIn_Pydantic):
    team_ = await Team.filter(name=team.dict()["name"]).first()
    if team_ is None:
        team_ = await Team.create(**team.dict(), **score.dict())
    else:
        await team_.score_history.add(Score(**score.dict()))
    await team_.save()
    return await Team_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(team_)
```

models.py:

```py
from datetime import date as dt

from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic.creator import pydantic_model_creator
from tortoise.models import Model


class Score(Model):
    id: int = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    score: int = fields.IntField()
    date: dt = fields.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.today_date()}: {self.score}"

    def today_date(self):
        return dt.today()

    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ['date']


class Team(Model):
    id: int = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name: str = fields.CharField(max_length=20, index=True)
    total_score: int = fields.IntField()
    score_history = fields.ManyToManyField("models.Score",
                                           related_name='score_history')

    def calculate_total_score(self):
        return self.score_history.all().aggregate(Sum('score'))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {self.total_score}"

    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ['total_score']


Score_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Score, name="Score")
Team_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Team, name="Team")
ScoreIn_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Score,
                                          name="Score",
                                          exclude_readonly=True)
TeamIn_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Team,
                                         name="TeamIn",
                                         exclude_readonly=True)
```

Error:
`AttributeError: type object 'Score' has no attribute 'date'`

Full Traceback:

```
> uvicorn scoreboard.main:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    server.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 49, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 56, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 308, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\scoreboard\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scoreboard.models import Score, Team, Team_Pydantic, TeamIn_Pydantic, ScoreIn_Pydantic
  File ".\scoreboard\models.py", line 41, in <module>
    Score_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Score, name="Score")
  File "C:\Users\navdh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tortoise\contrib\pydantic\creator.py", line 271, in pydantic_model_creator
    {
  File "C:\Users\navdh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tortoise\contrib\pydantic\creator.py", line 272, in <dictcomp>        
    k: {"field_type": callable, "function": getattr(cls, k), "description": None}
AttributeError: type object 'Score' has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

The official Tortoise docs with Pydantic Example clarifies the issue for me - https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/pydantic.html

Within the PydanticMeta subclass of the model, the 'computed' property  defines the names of the class methods of the model used to create that attribute. In my case the issue was resolved when I made that attribute callable, rather than simply declaring it an attribute at the top of the class.

It looks like this:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.TextField()
    # fullname = fields.TextField() # <-- This was wrong
    surname = fields.TextField()

    def full_name(self) -> str:   # <-- This was right
        return f"{self.name} {self.surname}"

    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ["full_name"]  # <-- Things here should be callable
```